# One virtual host on Apache is not visible on WAN, only on LAN

Tags: virtualhost, apache-2.4

I can't set virtual hosts on Apache 2.4.12 32 bit on a Windows 7. I was able to do this in previous versions, but now even following the official instructions I can't set up virtual hosts properly. I'm trying to set 2 virtual hosts, one for port `8080` and the other for port `8081`. I don't have a "main" server, only 2 virtual hosts set up. Locally, everything works fine. I can access them in `127.0.0.1:8080` and `127.0.0.1/8081`, but when I use `my Public IP:8080` and `my Public IP:8081`, only the virtual host on port 8080 is working. The one in port 8081 isn't being loaded by my public IP, though it's working with my local IP. Here is my httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerAdmin admin@vhosts
    DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/htdocs/vhost1"
    ServerName localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/vhost1-error.log"
</VirtualHost>

<Directory "${SRVROOT}/htdocs/vhost1">
    Options None
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:8081>
    ServerAdmin admin@vhosts
    DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/htdocs/vhost2"
    ServerName localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/vhost2-error.log"
</VirtualHost>

<Directory "${SRVROOT}/htdocs/vhost2">
    Options None
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Here are some relevant parts of httpd.conf:

```
Define SRVROOT "c:/Apache24"
ServerRoot "${SRVROOT}"

Listen 8080
Listen 8081

# all default modules are loaded in this part

# 'Main' server configuration are all commented because
# I don't want a 'Main' server, only virtual hosts
#ServerAdmin admin@server
#ServerName localhost
<Directory />
    Options None
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/htdocs"
# Includes are as they came by default, only these are enabled:
Include conf/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf
Include conf/extra/httpd-info.conf
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

# everything else as default
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just swap the ports of vhost1 and vhost2,restart service  and see if the vhost2 is working now & vhost1 stopped working?  If yes, its time to check your network.

Comment: @NehalDattani post your comment as an answer please, so I can accept it. It was a port forwarding issue indeed, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your configuration and have vhost2 listen on port 8080 while vhost1 listens on 8081. If vhost2 can be accessed now using public_ip:8080, it can be presumed that server configuration is ok and maybe its issue with your network configuration.

HTH.

Comment: It was a port forwarding issue that's now solved, thank you for your help!